# How Can I Check The Status (Active/Inactive) In Acumatica Event Handler?

Tags: acumatica

Can anybody tell me how to check if a Customer Status is Active or Inactive in Acumatica. I am using the following code but can't figure out what the real value for  should be:

```html
if (row != null){
        if (row.Status == <status.Active>){
          //DO SOMETHING
        }
        else{
          //DO SOMETHING ELSE
        }
      }
```

With what can I replace the  if I want to check if the Customer status is Active or not?

Thanks,
G

Comment: I'd like to help you, but in order to do this I need to know which Page you use, which element of screen, and which field. I ask this because Customer has different presence on different screens and graphs. So be more specific with your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you have something like :

```
if (row.status == Customer.status.Active)
```

It should work. You will need to have a using/reference for the AR objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can see what the attributes are on the status field by opening the customer form in Design mode. By doing that, you can see what field in the DAC it actually is and what is available in the dropdown for that field. Here are the attributes for the status field.

```
new string[] { Active, Hold, CreditHold, Inactive, OneTime },
new string[] { CR.Messages.Active, CR.Messages.Hold,CR.Messages.CreditHold, CR.Messages.Inactive, CR.Messages.OneTime }) { }
}}
[PXDBString(1, IsFixed = true)]
[PXDefault(status.Active)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Status")]
[status.List()]

// below are the values for the CR.Messages if you care to see

public const string Active = "Active";
public const string Hold = "On Hold";
public const string HoldPayments = "Hold Payments";
public const string Inactive = "Inactive";
public const string OneTime = "One-Time";
public const string CreditHold = "Credit Hold";
```

Further review of the source code shows that the customer status field is actually a field in the BAccount table called Status. It is a single character field and the value for Active = 'A',  Inactive = 'I'. (there are more values)

So, if you are simply wanting to know if the customer is Active, similar to what Max posted, you would simply do this in one of the event handlers where the current row is defined as row:

```
if (row.status == 'A')  // if customer status is Active...
{
//do something
}
```

There may be a constant you can use, which would be better.